# Securing spring boot endpoint using Azure AD

Tags: access-token, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to secure an endpoint in spring boot using Azure spring boot libraries. I'm following the samples from https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/master/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-active-directory-spring-boot-sample

I can't get a clear answer if I should use Id_token or Access_token when making the API call from my front end application written in React.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens
I think docs from this link above states that I should use Access_token to secure the endpoints but, in that azure-spring-boot-samples, they used id_token to make the API calls.

I've tried to use the same code and test an API call. API call is successful if I use id_token in header. It fails signature check if I pass access_token in header.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out after understanding the big picture. All applications either front end or back end most likely should be using different app IDs. On Azure portal I would define which app have permission to call which API. Then, when I get access token, I would have to specify what app I am getting access to. This is laid out in MSAL doc from Microsoft. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens

Comment: can you please share more details about your implementation. I am struggling with similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Also, only the access_token allows you to assert claims for things like Role Based Access Control in the token. The ID token is usually shorter lived and has less information. In general it is a better practice to use the access_token.